# Why do I have a terminal error in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm trying to learn Python using VS Code. Onde of my task is to opne a file from folder in VS Code nad then run a terminal but when I'm opening it i have error like below in temrinal

```
PS C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\Exercise Files> & C:/Users/ukasz/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/ukasz/Desktop/Exercise Files/Chap02/02_07_begin.py"
& : The term 'C:/Users/ukasz/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable progra
m. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & C:/Users/ukasz/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/ukasz/...on39/python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
PS C:\Users\Łukasz\Desktop\Exercise Files>
```

Could you explain me what I'm doing wrong? I'm not sure what's wrong in the file path and what I can change. I was just adding a file from my desktop, and also just installing a Python on my computer, nothing more.

If it help - I'm learning from the Linkedin Learnign, so I'm just trying to do what they say ;)

Comment: you appear to be losing the Ł in your name in the path? see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5736 perhaps